# Perl inheritance syntax error

Tags: perl, inheritance, syntax-error

I'm not a professional in Perl, but recently I had to implement inheritance with this language and got stuck.

Here is the screen shot of the sample (very simple) code and directory structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwv8t.png

The full error text is:

> Can't locate Parent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parent
>   module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
>   lib/Child.pm line 2. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Child.pm
>   line 2. Compilation failed in require.

If there is some problem with the screen shot:

Directory tree:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── Child.pm
│   └── Parent.pm
├── main.pl
└── MyProject.komodoproject
```

main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib::Child;
```

lib/Parent.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package lib::Parent;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_for) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->_init($arg_for);
    return $self;
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->{prop1} = $arg_for{prop1};
    $self->{prop2} = $arg_for{prop2};
}

1;
```

lib/Child.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Parent;
package lib::Child;
@ISA = qw(Parent);

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_for) = @_;
    my ($self) = Parent->new($arg_for);
    $self->_init($arg_for);
    return (bless ($self, $class));
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->{param1} = $arg_for{param1};
    $self->{param2} = 'param2';
}

1;
```

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: The error message fom this code is actually `Can't locate package Parent for @lib::Child::ISA`, which is subtly different.

Comment: @Borodin
How is that? I just did a "copy/paste" thing. The error is still the same: in Komodo IDE, in Eclipse, and in CLI:
`Can't locate Parent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parent module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at lib/Child.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Child.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require at ./main.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./main.pl line 5.`

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of Perl. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have access only to a Windows system at present, which means I was getting problems with the clash between your `Parent` module and the core `parent` pragma.

I have changed the name to `Father`, and I suggest you install these files on your own system *all in the same directory* and work from there. Then at least we will both know where you are!

It looks like you come from a Python background? There is no need for a separate `_init` method, as all work like that can be written in `new`. I have written `Father` so that it remembers a `father_arg`, and `Child` so that it has a `child_arg` as well as the `father_arg` inherited from the base class.

Here is `main.pl`. It creates one object of each type and uses the accessors to display the stored arguments from each.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Father;
use Child;

my $father = Father->new('Father1');
my $child  = Child->new('Father2', 'Child');

say $father->father_arg;
say $child->father_arg;
say $child->child_arg;
```

Here is `Father.pm`. Remember that it should be in the same directory as `main.pl` and the other module file. It is also best to remove any other module files that perl may find instead of the correct ones: `your old`Child.pm`, for instance.

The constructor `new` creates an anonymous hash, which is the usual base for objects but you can use any reference you like. It saves the passed parameter undef the `father_arg` key of the hash, and returns the blessed reference. The accessor `father_arg` just takes `$self` from the parameter list and uses it to return the `father_arg` element.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Father;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg) = @_;
    my $self = { father_arg => $arg };
    bless $self, $class;
}


sub father_arg {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{father_arg};
}

1;
```

Here is `Child.pm`. It uses `use parent 'Father'` to establish that it inherits from the `Father` module. This does something similar to `use Father; our @ISA; push @ISA, 'Father';` but more concisely.

The constructor has *two* arguments this time in addition to the class name, and it needs to do its own stuff, as well as executing the constructor for `Father`. The pseudo-class `SUPER` is used for this, which will call the current class's base class without mentioning it explicitly. The `father_arg` value is passed to this initial constructor, which can then be modified to subclass the object by also adding the `child_arg` value. Then all that is necessary is to return the value of `$self` (already blessed by `Father::new`.

The `father_arg` accessor will be inherited from the base class, and a new `child_arg` accessor will allow the additional data to be recalled.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Child;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Father';

sub new {
    my ($class, $father_arg, $child_arg) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($father_arg);
    $self->{child_arg} = $child_arg;
    $self;
}

sub child_arg {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{child_arg};
}

1;
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The major problem is that you are confusing yourself by putting the modules in the `lib` directory. This works partially because the current directory `.` appears in `@ISA`, so Perl will look there for the modules. But `lib/Child.pm` starts with

```
use Parent;
package lib::Child;
@ISA = qw(Parent);
```

which uses the wrong names for the packages. This should be

```
package lib::Child;
use lib::Parent;
@ISA = qw(lib::Parent);
```

or, better,

```
package lib::Child;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent qw(lib::Parent);
```

Note that the `package` statement sets the current namespace, and it isn't unusual for `use` to import symbols into the current namespace. So your original `use Parent` was at a point where the current namespace was the default `main`, and then immediately change to `lib::Child` which has nothing imported. You should ordinarily put the `package` statement at the top of the code (together with `use strict` and `use warnings` in *every* Perl source file) but you got away with it here because you are using inheritance rather than importing symbols.

As long as your current working directory is the same as your source code directory, you can get away with putting the module files in the same place, and dropping the `lib` from the names. If you really want to use a separate directory for the modules then you can write

```
use lib '/path/to/lib';
```

at the start of `main.pl`, and the package names will be *relative* to this from thereon. Or you may want to make use of the environment variable `PERL5LIB` which adds the contents of the variable to the *beginning* of the path at the start of each program run.

You may find it useful to run just `perl -V` on the command line. That will show you the contents of `@INC`, which is where the perl interpreter searches for the modules that you `use`, and it will show you the effect of any changes to `PERL5LIB` as well.

Your `@INC` seems a little strange, as it contains `.`  *twice* -- once at the beginning and once at the end. It looks like this

```
@INC contains:
.
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.18
/usr/share/perl/5.18
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
.
```

and that usually indicates that you already have `PERL5LIB` set to `.`.

It may be better for you if you use one of the directories that you have access to that is already in the search list, such as `/etc/perl` or `/usr/lib/perl5`. But you should check what's already in there to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and examples! I still have issues though... The 1st solution removes compilation errors, but the IDE still complains `Can't locate lib/Parent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::Parent module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .).`; the 2nd solution makes the IDE to complain in a similar way + compilation error `Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name` when trying to call a parent property..

Comment: @a1111exe: What is the IDE saying? There are *two* places where you need to change `Parent` to `lib::Parent`. I suggest you use the code for `lib/Child.pm` in my solution after *“or, better”*

Comment: I've written a set of code in a separate solution that works fine for me, but I don't have access to Komodo so I can't replicate your environment. I think it should be fine.

Comment: The only IDEs for Perl that I know are Komodo and Eclipse (EPIC). I'd prefer to work with Vim, but I'm not (yet) comfortable with Perl CLI debugging. I tried Padre also, but it was a bit too painful experience for me. Eclipse seems to be OK but it goes completely mad when there are zillions of files in a project directory tree (some old production app). If you know some nice IDE for Perl (like Phpstorm for PHP) please share :)

Comment: Thanks again for your thorough explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

`lib` should just be a library directory, and not actually part of the package names.

The following is how I would rework your files:

`main.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib";

use Child;
```

`lib/Parent.pm`

```
package Parent;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_for) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->_init($arg_for);
    return $self;
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->{prop1} = $arg_for{prop1};
    $self->{prop2} = $arg_for{prop2};
}

1;
```

`lib/Child.pm`

```
package Child;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parent;
our @ISA = qw(Parent);

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_for) = @_;
    my ($self) = Parent->new($arg_for);
    $self->_init($arg_for);
    return (bless ($self, $class));
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->{param1} = $arg_for{param1};
    $self->{param2} = 'param2';
}

1;
```

Comment: Not quite solid, as the you have made the library directory dependent on the current working directory. It's always best to use an absolute path for that.

Comment: Yes, that's the usual solution. But you probably know that it unnecessarily searches `PATH` for the code, and may well pick up the wrong thing. I quite like [`FindBin::Real`](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin::Real) but there are a couple other solutions.

Comment: `$Bin` fails to handle symlinks to the program, unlike `$RealBin`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank everyone, especially @Borodin and @Miller for your effort!

Here is the fully working example (based on the 2nd solution from @Borodin):

Directory tree:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── Child.pm
│   └── Parent.pm
├── main.pl
└── MyProject.komodoproject
```

main.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib::Child;

my $child = lib::Child->new({
    prop1 => 'prop1',
    param1 => 'param1',
    prop2 => 'prop2',
    param3 => 'param3',
    param2 => 'param2',
});

print "prop1 $child->{prop1}\n";
print "prop2 $child->{prop2}\n";
print "param1 $child->{param1}\n";
print "param2 $child->{param2}\n";
print "param3 $child->{param3}\n";
```

lib/Parent.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package lib::Parent;

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg_for) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->_init($arg_for);
    return $self;
}

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->{prop1} = $arg_for{prop1};
    $self->{prop2} = $arg_for{prop2};
}

1;
```

lib/Child.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package lib::Child;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent qw(lib::Parent);

sub _init {
    my ($self, $arg_for) = @_;
    my %arg_for = %$arg_for;

    $self->SUPER::_init(\%arg_for);

    $self->{param1} = $arg_for{param1};
    $self->{param2} = 'param2';
    $self->{param3} = $self->test();
}

sub test {
    my $self = shift;
    my $prop1 = 'other';
    if ($self->{prop1} =~ m/\.txt$/) {
        $prop1 = 'text';
    }
    return $prop1;
}

1;
```

The output is:

```
prop1 prop1
prop2 prop2
param1 param1
param2 param2
param3 other
```

The only thing is that the IDE still cries on line 6 in Child.pm:

Komodo:

`Can't locate lib/Parent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::Parent module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl/5.18/parent.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Eclipse:

`Can't locate lib/Parent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::Parent module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) in /usr/share/perl/5.18/parent.pm line 20    Child.pm    /Inheritance/lib    Unknown Perl Problem`

However, both play the main.pl file without any problem. In CLI it runs perfect also. So it seems to be good enough (sigh).

Comment: You're making assumptions about the current working directory. Add `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;` to `main.pl`. Better yet, add `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/lib";` to `main.pl`, and get rid of `lib::` everywhere. That would be a far more standard architechture.

Comment: @a1111exe: Your problem seems to be that the `.` in `@INC` refers to a different place when run under an IDE from when it is run on the command line. I think *everyone* has told you that the `lib` is a problem. If you put everything in the same directory, as I suggested, and remove `lib::` from everywhere, then you should run just fine. If you must use a separate library directory, then define it to be an absolute path with `use lib` or by setting `PERL5LIB` as I described, or pick a relatively unpopulated one from the list of directories already in `@INC`.

Comment: And why do you still have an `_init`? You seem to be splitting `new` for no particular reason, and no one familiar with Perl will thank you.